# Convert percent value to decimal value in PHP

Tags: php, decimal

How to convert percent value to decimal value in PHP to be used in a computation?

Example: 6.15% = .0615

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$dec = $pct / 100.00;

// if you actually have a % sign in $pct strip it out
$pct = '15%';
$dec = str_replace('%', '', $pct) / 100.00;
```

Answer (score 19):

```
echo floatval("6.15%") / 100.00;
```

Comment: Thank you. From 9 years in the future ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
function percentToDecimal($percent): float
{
    $percent = str_replace('%', '', $percent);
    return $percent / 100.00;
}
```